# IndexErrror: out of bounds

Tags: python, pandas, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to perform a `pivot_table` function on a dataset, with 'userID' as the index but it gives an `Indexerror: index 640985038 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 640958005`

but the highest 'userID' is only 278854.  I don't understand why this error is coming up at all anyways.

```
rating_crosstab = combined_books.pivot_table(values='bookRating', index='userID',columns='bookTitle', fill_value=0)
```

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFJDp.png)

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10582

Comment: Ran into a similar issue a while back, I had to use SQL instead.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set?

Comment: @Dodge I attached an image into the body of my question.  'Dataset'

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is still an open bug https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12210 and https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10582.

Answer (score 0):

As Tyger pointed out, you are very probably running out of memory because Pandas `pivot_table` operations are very [memory intensive](http://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10582).

You could probably split up your dataframe, do `pivot_table` on each block and put them back together. This would be longer but probably work.

Comment: Yeah the original dataset has 1149780 rows.  The userIDs are integers much higher like 640958005 but that doesnt reflect the size of the dataframe.  Maybe if I convert them to strings and then back to integers after the pivot?